# What does Keras.io.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences do?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

The Keras documentation could be improved here. After reading through this, I still do not understand what this does exactly: [Keras.io.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/)

Could someone illuminate what this function does, and ideally provide an example?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`pad_sequences` is used to ensure that all sequences in a list have the same length. By default this is done by padding `0` in the beginning of each sequence until each sequence has the same length as the longest sequence.

For example

```
>>> pad_sequences([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8]])
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

`[3, 4, 5, 6]` is the longest sequence, so `0` will be padded to the other sequences so their length matches `[3, 4, 5, 6]`.

If you rather want to pad to the end of the sequences you can set `padding='post'`.

If you want to specify the maximum length of each sequence you can use the `maxlen` argument. This will truncate all sequences longer than `maxlen`.

```
>>> pad_sequences([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8]], maxlen=3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

Now each sequence have the length 3 instead.

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/) one can control the truncation with the pad_sequences. By default truncating is set to `pre`, which truncates the beginning part of the sequence. If you rather want to truncate the end part of the sequence you can set it to `post`.

Comment: while truncating sequences longer than `maxlen`, is the beginning part of the sequence always removed or the numbers are chosen randomly?

Comment: @kasheemlew According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/), you can control this with the `truncating` argument of `pad_sequences`. By default `truncating` is set to `'pre'`, which truncates the beginning part of the sequence. If you rather want to truncate the end part of the sequence you can set it to `'post'`.

Comment: @oscfri Any idea on how do you perform padding on tensor without using reshape as reshape breaks gradients flow in tensorflow

Comment: @DeepakM As I'm aware of reshape shouldn't break the gradient flow. I've done it many times without any issue. I'd recommend you to make a new question about your issue. Have you had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836859/why-does-tensorflow-reshape-tf-reshape-break-the-flow-of-gradients?rq=1)?

Comment: Such an amazing explanation. Thank you very much

Comment: @oscfri  sir i have question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429393/how-to-convert-pandas-multiple-columns-of-text-into-tensors/68432623?noredirect=1#comment121992042_68432623.         But after converting each column into tensors. How to implement lstm or other models. Someone suggested pad_sequence and i am not sure how it would be done. Can you please answer there?

Comment: @irfan I recommend you to ask a new separate question about your current problem. Keep in mind to ask a clear question (show your progress so far and describe clearly what you're aiming to do). I may help to answer when I got time, unless someone is quicker to help you before me.

Comment: @oscfri sir thank you so much. here is the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107390/implication-of-deep-learning-model-on-nlp-tabular-data I think this question will help a lot of people including me.

Answer (score 6):

some examples:

```py
>>> from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

>>> # add the 0's on the beginning of sequences
>>> pad_sequences(a)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 7, 8]])

>>> # add the 0's on the end of sequences
>>> pad_sequences(a, padding="post")
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 0, 0]])

>>> # add a limit length of sequences
>>> pad_sequences(a, maxlen=3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 8]])


>>> # add a limit length on the end of sequences
>>> pad_sequences(a, maxlen=3, padding="post")
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 0]])
```

Comment: @oscfri  sir i have question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429393/how-to-convert-pandas-multiple-columns-of-text-into-tensors/68432623?noredirect=1#comment121992042_68432623.         But after converting each column into tensors. How to implement Lstm or other models. Someone suggested pad_sequence and I am not sure how it would be done. Can you please answer there?

Comment: Your column has to be only containing numerical values, than use `pad_sequences` to made all batches equally sized. Than convert all data in the column between 0-1.
Models can only handle 1 input size.