# Use tf.gradients or tf.hessians on flattened parameter tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, hessian-matrix

Let's say I want to compute the Hessian of a scalar-valued function with respect to some parameters W (e.g the weights and biases of a feed-forward neural network).
If you consider the following code, implementing a two-dimensional linear model trained to minimize a MSE loss:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])  #inputs
t = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,])  #labels
W = tf.placeholder(np.eye(2), dtype=tf.float32)  #weights

preds = tf.matmul(x, W)  #linear model
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(preds-t), axis=0) #mse loss

params = tf.trainable_variables() 
hessian = tf.hessians(loss, params)
```

you'd expect `session.run(tf.hessian,feed_dict={})` to return a 2x2 matrix (equal to W). It turns out that because `params`is a 2x2 tensor, the output is rather a tensor with shape [2, 2, 2, 2]. While I can easily reshape the tensor to obtain the matrix I want, it seems that this operation might be extremely cumbersome when `params`becomes a list of tensors of varying size (i.e when the model is a deep neural network for instance).

It seems that are two ways around this:

- Flatten `params` to be a 1D tensor called `flat_params`:

  ```
  flat_params = tf.concat([tf.reshape(p, [-1]) for p in params])
  ```

  so that `tf.hessians(loss, flat_params)` naturally returns a 2x2 matrix. However as noted in [Why does Tensorflow Reshape tf.reshape() break the flow of gradients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836859/why-does-tensorflow-reshape-tf-reshape-break-the-flow-of-gradients) for tf.gradients (but also holds for tf.hessians), tensorflow is not able to see the symbolic link in the graph between `params`and `flat_params` and `tf.hessians(loss, flat_params)` will raise an error as the gradients will be seen as `None`.
- In https://afqueiruga.github.io/tensorflow/2017/12/28/hessian-mnist.html, the author of the code goes the other way, and first create the flat parameter and reshapes its parts into `self.params`. This trick does work and gets you the hessian with its *expected* shape (2x2 matrix). However, it seems to me that this will be cumbersome to use when you have a complex model, and impossible to apply if you create your model via built-in functions (like `tf.layers.dense`, ..).

Is there no straight-forward way to get the Hessian matrix (as in the 2x2 matrix in this example) from `tf.hessians`, when `self.params` is a list of tensor of arbitrary shapes? If not, how can you automatize the reshaping of the output tensor of `tf.hessians`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out (per TensorFlow r1.13) that if len(xs) > 1, then tf.hessians(ys, xs) returns tensors corresponding to only the block diagonal submatrices of the full Hessian matrix. Full story and solutions in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.05559, and code at https://github.com/gknilsen/pyhessian