# Workaround tf.reshape breaking the flow of the gradient (jacobian)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a program in which I'm trying to calculate the jacobian of a neural network, but in order to properly define the jacobian I used `tf.reshape`to make the data vectors (as far as I know, jacobian: dy/dx is only defined when y and x are vectors (not matrices nor tensors))
this is my code

```
@tf.function
def A_calculator():
  with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as gtape:
      noise=tf.random.normal([1000, 100])
      gtape.watch(noisex)
      fakenoise=tf.reshape(gen(noise),[1000,-1])
      reshaped_noise=tf.reshape(noise,[1000,-1])
  #caulculate jacobian
  Jz=gtape.batch_jacobian(fakenoise,reshaped_noise)
  return Jz
```

where `gen`is a neural network that returns an image(generator)
My problem is that `Jz` is always a tensor with zero as elements
I searched for a solution for this but the closest thing was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836859/why-does-tensorflow-reshape-tf-reshape-break-the-flow-of-gradients)(this is what made me suspect that the problem is `tf.reshape`), but the solution there doesn't solve my problem as I want to do reshape after I insert the value to the function`gen`, does anybody know how solve this ? or why `Jz` always gives a tensor with zero values ?

Comment: `fakenoise` in no way depends on `reshaped_noise`, meaning changing the latter does not change the former, meaning the gradient of `fakenoise` wrt `reshaped_noise` is 0. All working as intended.

Comment: @xdurch0 True, Thank you, I didn't think that reshape would create a totally different variable,  that was my mistake. 
I removed the reshape and now it works, but it is pretty slow now, would you suggest a different method to make it faster

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping every tensor is unnecessary, as reshaping (1000,100) tensor to(1000,-1) will result in same shape. Skip reshaping altogether at all stages.

Please check the generator it could take a lot of time to produce the "fakenoise"