# Keras tutorial max_length

Tags: keras

I'm working my way through this Keras tutorial [Text classification with movie reviews](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification) on the Keras website.

They use a variable `max_length` which they set to 256. I'm not sure I understand where this is coming from. When I check the max length of all the train_data, I get 2494

`max(len(l) for l in train_data)
 2494`

This tutorial also uses a `GlobalAveragePooling1D` as its second layer, which I'm also not understanding, since the input if fixed to 256.

If anyone can offer insight, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SO question addressing the pad_sequences function that may be helpful.
[What does Keras.io.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943291/what-does-keras-io-preprocessing-sequence-pad-sequences-do)

As far as *why* they chose 256 as the max length...it's arbitrary.  They need all the sequences the same length so they selected a reasonable value. And, yes, some will end up being truncated. A histogram of the lengths would give you an idea how many will be truncated.  A quick google yields a histogram:

[image]

My advice is to work through the tutorial as-is...then try a few different values of that max-length and see how it affects the results.  In practice, a value *must* be selected.