# How to change the dtype of an "object" to float32?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm actually trying to program a Keras Model. In my point of view, a keras Model needs a list of np.arrays as x (or a Numpy Array). In my case x is looking like this:

```
print(training.dtype)
```

> object

```
print(training.shape)
```

> (406,)

```
print(training[0].dtype)
```

> float64

```
print(training[0].shape)
```

> (5140, 5)

This is the size of my Train data (x). If I want to train the model I get this error:

> return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

That's why I think, I prepared the data wrong. If I want to convert them with .astype to float32, I get the same error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check the length or shape of the items used to make `train2`.  Looks like they vary in size.

Comment: Did you try `train2 = np.array(train2)`? What does it say?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, they variate in size. Is this a problem for my model?

Comment: @sebrockm  Yes, im doing it some lines before. It compiles with no error.

Comment: @MareSeestern yes, varying sizes are a problem. Not so much for your model, but for numpy. You will need to either truncate big arrays or add padding to small ones. If you make all of them the same size (e.g. `(1140, 9)`) then `np.array()` will generate one single numpy array of size `(907, 1140, 9)` which is what `model.fit()` expects.

Comment: @sebrockm Thanks, a lot for your help. I will try it. But what could I add to the small one? None? or 0?

Comment: @MareSeestern That depends on your model. Usually `0` is a good value for padding. But if `0` is a value that is otherwise meaningful, this may be an issue. You might also want to have a look at how masking works in Keras and determine if that is suitable for your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entries in `train2` do not all have the same size, you will need to pad them. As this is something that needs to be done quite regularly, Keras offers a function for this: [`pad_sequences`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences)

Once they all are the same size, `np.array(train2)` will create one single numpy array that you can pass to `model.fit()`.

Depending on your model, the extra data you are adding this way may or may not be an issue. A common way to deal with this is [Masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking). Use this to generate a mask that will automatically be passed down the model so that certain values (the values you added via padding) are ignored. Note however, that not all layers support masking, so maybe this is not an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not changing the type. The issue is in the batch samples not being of the same size, so no np array could be created. You can solve this by using padding as mentioned in the comments. Have a look at keras `pad_sequences` [What does Keras.io.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943291/what-does-keras-io-preprocessing-sequence-pad-sequences-do)